# Moving inner div to the bottom-right corner of the outer parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like my inner `div` to be on the bottom-right corner of the outer div, by using `float: right`, but for some reason, it'll staying on the bottom-left corner. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#outer {
width:100%;
height:20%;
border: 1px solid black; 
position: absolute;  
} 
#inner {
width: 50px
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
position: absolute;
float: right;  
bottom: 0;  
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'>
<div id = 'inner'>
bottom-right corner; 
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `right: 0` instead.

Floating the element won't have any effect on it if it's absolutely positioned.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
#inner {
  width: 50px height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'>
    bottom-right corner;
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change css property for outer div as below:

```
#inner {
     width: 50px
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0; 
     right:0
}
```